# Protractor - count elements in repeater and print it

Tags: angularjs, testing, angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor, end-to-end

I'm trying to count the elements in repeater and to print it to console.

This is the markup:

```
<div class="col-md-3 ng-scope" ng-repeat="app in userApps" >...< /div>
```

currently I'm counting and comparing:

```
expect(element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count()).toEqual(4);
```

it works, but I want to be able to print it also.

I've tried this:

```
var rows = element.all(by.repeater("app in userApps"));
var sum = rows.count(); 
console.log(sum.getText());
```

but I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getText'
```

there are two question actually-
1. am I doing it the correct way?
2. how do I print it to console?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you actually want to print the count and not the entire content, right?

```
element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count().then(function(count) {
  console.log(count);
});
```

Comment: you are right. it is what i meant. but now, with your code I'm getting this error immediately:      SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
   Stacktrace:
     SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Function.promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:650:9)

Comment: it Works! just needed to add ';' and ');'  :    element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count().then(function(count) {
  console.log(count);
});   thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

the more 'modern' way of doing this is using `async/await`

```
it('test case', async () => {
  let count = await element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count();
  console.log(count);
});
```