# Why does Protractor sometimes returns a promise and sometimes returns a value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

In the [official documentation](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial) you can find the following code:

```
var history = element.all(by.repeater('result in memory'));
expect(history.count()).toEqual(2);
```

But you can also find [examples using promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28075298/2352017)

```
element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count().then(function(count) {
    console.log(count);
});
```

So why does Protractor sometimes returns a promise and sometimes it returns a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`history.count()` does return a promise, but Protractor adapts Jasmine `expect` to understand promises.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md

Answer (score 3):

It always returns a promise, it's just that `expect` is patched to handle them by adding them to the [control-flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) so that they get executed and resolved in the proper order.

Answer (score 2):

> the protractor folks "patched" jasmine to be promise aware. that is,
>   the expect statement does duck-typing -- if it is a promise, it waits
>   for it to resolve and executes the underlying assertion. if it is any
>   other type, it executes the assertion as it would in any other jasmine
>   world.

[source](http://jessehouse.com/blog/2014/05/17/protractor-promises-all-the-way-down/#disqus_thread)